# jquery animate transform:rotate

Tags: jquery, animation, rotation

I have the following image which i am trying to animate the rotation:

[image]

My css currently for the image is this (the image has a class of "p5easy":

```
.p5easy{ 
   transform:rotate(-90deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

I am then using jQuery to try and animate the image. I am doing the following:

```
$('.p5easy').delay(0).show().animate({'-webkit-transform':'rotate(0deg)'},{duration: 1000});
```

Im not quite sure but this doesnt work. Am i approaching this in the right way? Does jQuery animate support rotation, or do i need another plugin for this?

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jvpEN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('.p5easy').animate({  textIndent: 0 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');
```

Comment: Thanks, i am looking for it to be an animated transition though. Is this possible?

Comment: do you mean long rotation?

Comment: Say i wanted to position it relative, left:0px; and then wanted to aniamte it to sat left:450px; is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably a bit (a year) late, but you can try one of these:
http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/08/jquery-flip-effect-plugin-examples/